# Is there any way to convert yaml file (uploaded in streamlit) into python dictionary?

Tags: python, yaml, streamlit

I am working on streamlit application where I have to upload some yaml config file via streamlit.sidebar.file_uploader() and be able to access parameters stored in the file.

```
import streamlit as st
import yaml

config = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload config file")

if config is not None:

  with open(config, 'r') as uploaded_config:
    loaded_config = yaml.safe_load(uploaded_config)

  st.write(loaded_config['scoring'])
```

But when I am trying to read uploaded yaml file as dict it returns the error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile
Traceback:
File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/npextension_app_env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
with open(config, 'r') as uploaded_config:
```

If I use .getvalue() to get bytes file instead of UploadedFile like this:

```
import streamlit as st
import yaml

config = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload config file")

if config is not None:

  with open(config.getvalue(), 'r') as uploaded_config:
    loaded_config = yaml.safe_load(uploaded_config)

  st.write(loaded_config['scoring'])
```

It returns another error:

```
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: b'features_list:\n - NO2 Mean\n - 03 Mean\n - 
SO2 Mean\n - is_weekend\n\nevents_list:\n - is_xmas\n\nds: Date Local\n\ny: CO Mean\n\nscoring: mae\n\nfreq: D\n\ntest_p: 
0.06\n\nvalid_p: 0.1\n\nk: 3\n'
Traceback:
File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/npextension_app_env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
with open(config.getvalue(), 'r') as uploaded_config:
```

My yaml file looks like this:

```
features_list:
  - NO2 Mean
  - 03 Mean
  - SO2 Mean
  - is_weekend
events_list:
  - is_xmas
ds: Date Local
y: CO Mean
scoring: mae
freq: D
test_p: 0.06
valid_p: 0.1
k: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the mistake.
Instead of using:

```
with open(config, 'r') as uploaded_config:
 loaded_config = yaml.safe_load(uploaded_config)
```

use this:

```
loaded_config = yaml.safe_load(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import yaml

with open("/home/ubuntu/data.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        parsed_yaml=yaml.safe_load(stream)
        print(parsed_yaml)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

i've found this code on https://fedingo.com/how-to-read-yaml-file-to-dict-in-python/

Comment: The idea is to read yaml file from streamlit file uploader, not just using local path.